# Tradition as subject of the sentence

Tags: expressions

Do "traditions say" or "traditions hold" or do they not have a verb and are usually the object rather than subject of the sentence?

Comment: Maybe "tradition dictates that such and such should be done"...

Comment: @Anonymous or *tradition requires ...*

Comment: If you're making tradition do something, you're anthropomorphizing it (which is perfectly fine) and you can use pretty much any verb.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is mostly used as the subject and predicate nominative in a sentence.

This *tradition* is *one* found among the peoples of Asia.

There are many, many *traditions* found all over the world [subject]. Local *traditions*, are probably the most widely known to those living in a community [subject]. They try to stop certain *traditions* in many countries because the leaders believe *they* are no longer relative to the people at large [direct object of the verb "stop" in the infinitive phrase/subject of dependent clause]. However, *they*, the *traditions*, still persist [subject/appositive]. This last ceremony officially ends the local *tradition* of putting flowers on the graves of children when spring arrives [direct object].